# Unable to export a formatted graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export

I'm looking to export a small graph in the documentation to a vector file, such that it's appearance doesn't change.

Originally, I wanted to use the following example from the doc page of  `AdjacencyList[]` with a single tweak to the vertex label color. Why? Because I liked the spacing it had on its labels, as you can see:

[image]

So I evaluated the cell, hoping to then add options programmatically, but simply evaluating it made the nice vertex formatting go away:

[image]

Ok, so I stepped back and just tried to export it as-is to any (vector) format at all. First, I tried converting it to graphics with the right click menu, no luck:

[image]

Then I tried saving to a variety file types, but again nothing I exported looked anything like the original graph, for example:

[image]

Interestingly, I found out that Postscript isn't even supported (it is an option and is supposed to be):

[image]

Finally, I tried the file menu option for saving a selection, *but this does nothing* or fails silently!

[image]

I'm at a loss that such a simple thing is evading me.

Comment: I think a better title would be less about the export and more about the formatting. In this case the `Export` is seemingly distinct from the problem, even though it is why you want the problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use vertex names as the image of the vertices is

```
CompleteGraph[5, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image]

As you can see, the spacing is not great.  *The edges overlap with the vertices.*  When this happens, the first thing you should try is

```
CompleteGraph[5, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

This almost always fixes this problem.  The most common use case is directed graphs where part of the arrowhead overlaps with the vertex.  But I also use it in this specific situation.

If you want to tweak the spacing further, use `VertexSize`.

```
CompleteGraph[5, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know of a simple option to set the edges to use CapForm?

Comment: @M.R. `CompleteGraph[5, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]], 
 VertexSize -> 0.2]`

Comment: Ah, I see the PerformanceGoal activates the CapForm. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing - how to make the endpoints equidistant from the glyph? Perhaps that's too big a question for a comment...

Comment: @M.R. If you want it equidistant from the center of each glyph (not their bounding box), then you can use something similar to `CompleteGraph[5, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
  VertexLabelStyle -> Large, 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]], 
 VertexSize -> 0.2]`.  A bonus is that you can control the glyph style using `VertexLabelStyle`.

Comment: That’s almost what I’m after, but I think I’ll post a separate question with the specifics

Comment: Here's the separate question, I added some pictures to help convey what I'm trying to do: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164211/better-aesthetics-for-graph-vertices

Answer (score 4):

`Graph` formatting has changed recently. The `Box` form it used to have is no longer the one it has.

So the easiest thing to do is probably just to regenerate your graph with formatting:

```
CompleteGraph[5,
 VertexShape -> Table[n -> Graphics[Inset[Style[n, Black]]], {n, 5}],
 VertexSize -> .25,
 ImageSize -> 100
 ]
```

[image: ggg]

Szabolcs would know better than I, though, as to how to get that type of white-space without such fine-tuning

Comment: Thanks! How did you find this out?

Comment: The box formatting thing? I've just looked at a bunch of the box structures when I tried to implement a click-and-drag format-able graph. Noticed that most of them in the documentation notebooks are different from the box structures that are spit out now.

Comment: With this new syntax, is there an easy way to get the edge lines to have CapForm["Round"], without extracting them and using EdgeShapeFunction?

Comment: When the vertices overlap with the edges, the usual fix is `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`.  I learned it from @halmir.

Comment: @M.R. I think you should un-accept this answer in favor of Sabolcs'. His is definitely less fine-tuned.