# Better aesthetics for graph vertices?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, formatting, style

This is a follow-up question to: [Unable to export a formatted graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164167/unable-to-export-a-formatted-graph)

I trying to layout a graph so that if you zoom in on a vertex, **things look nice**. To see what I mean by nice, let me just describe how I would like to make the edges connect to the vertices with a few examples:

Here's my starting point, with a simple graph using a typical layout:

```
CompleteGraph[5, 
 VertexShape -> 
  Table[n -> 
    Graphics[
     Inset[Style[n, FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro", FontSize -> 25, 
       Background -> None]]], {n, 5}], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]], 
 VertexSize -> 0.25, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

This looks great, but if you zoom in on the vertices, we can start to see some issues. The minimum distances from the glyph to the edges vary a lot, moreover *the curve through the edge endpoints isn't short and smooth*.

[image]

So we don't simply want our edge endpoints equidistant from the vertex center coordinate. Instead we want edges sensitive to some bounding oval of the vertex label's glyph, like this:

[image]

Here's another more detailed example for vertex 3, which shows on the left what we start with, and and the right what I want.

[image]

Perhaps there's a simple way to do this, `RegionNearest` comes to mind, but may be overkill:

```
r = RegionNearest[Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 4}], {5, 5}];
Graphics[{{LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 4}]}, 
  Inset[Style["3", FontSize -> 250, FontColor -> Black], {0, 
    0}], {PointSize[Large], {Red, Point[{5, 5}]}, {Blue, Point[r]}, 
   Line[{{5, 5}, r}]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
cg = CompleteGraph[7, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[7] -> (Placed[Style[#, 25], Center] & /@ Range[7])], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro"], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]], 
 VertexSize -> Scaled[0.01], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 ImageSize -> 200, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[], Disk[#, Scaled@{3/40, .1}]}} &)]
```

[image]

Use `EdgeForm[Gray]` to get

[image]

```
ImageCrop[Rasterize@Magnify[%, 5], {300, 300}, {1, -.7}]
```

[image]

**Update from Comments:**

To fix the misaligned labels (they don't look "centered"), @kglr suggested:

```
graphicsNumbers = 
  Graphics[First[
      First[ImportString[
        ExportString[
         Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.1], 
          FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro"], "PDF"], "PDF", 
        "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]] & /@ Range[7];
cg = CompleteGraph[7, 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Thread[Range[
      7] -> (Placed[
         Graphics[Inset[#, {1/2, 1/2}, Automatic, Scaled[.1]]], 
         Center] & /@ graphicsNumbers)], 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]], 
  VertexSize -> Scaled[0.01], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ImageSize -> 200, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[], 
       Disk[#, Scaled@{3/40, .1}]}} &), Background -> None]
```

But this produces the same graph as above.

Comment: I noticed, If you look at the 7, 6, 4, 3, or 2, it’s a little bit off. Can we enter the ellipse at the centroid of the number?

Comment: @M.R., I think it is related to the fonts rendering off- center issue: see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137873/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/125). Using Graphics versions of fonts should make it better.

Comment: by graphics version of fonts do you mean using Inset or something else?

Comment: @M.R. I meant using `Inset`; e.g.,  something like   `graphicsNumbers = 
  Graphics[First[ First[ImportString[ ExportString[
         Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.1], 
          FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro"], "PDF"], "PDF", 
        "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]] & /@ Range[7];` and changing the vertex labels option to `VertexLabels ->  Thread[Range[
    7] -> (Placed[ Graphics[Inset[#, {1/2, 1/2}, Automatic, Scaled[.1]]], 
       Center] & /@ graphicsNumbers)]`.

Comment: I added that to your answer, but I zoomed in and saw that it has no effect

Comment: I'd rather not have to use drawing tools to try and tweak it by hand

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @M.R. right. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Could use VertexSize -> {a, b}:

```
CompleteGraph[5, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 
  Directive[FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro", FontSize -> 25], 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]], 
 VertexSize -> {.15, .2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 ImageSize -> 200]
```

Comment: Do you have any tips for [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164671/12)?