# Remove or change edge weights of graph with good performance

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

How can I remove edge weights from a graph, or change all edge weights in one go, with good performance, *while preserving edge ordering*?

Consider this weight vector and unweighted graph:

```
weights = RandomReal[1, 5000];
g = RandomGraph[{1000, 5000}];
```

Adding the weights to the graph is very fast:

```
wg = Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> weights]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.000010, Null} *)
```

The only way I know to either remove all these weights, or to change the entire edge-weight vector, is to re-build the graph.  This is much too slow for my purposes.

```
g2 = Graph[VertexList[wg], EdgeList[wg]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0027, Null} *)

wg2 = Graph[VertexList[wg], EdgeList[wg], EdgeWeight -> 2 weights]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0028, Null} *)
```

Is there a much faster way?  I am looking for something comparable in performance to setting the initial weights.

---

**Update:**

Originally I neglected to say that I strongly prefer a solution that maintains edges ordering.  Consider for example the task of computing the `EdgeBetwennessCentrality` of a weighted and unweighted version of a graph. The result of this function depends on edge ordering.

Carl's original answer based on `Nucleus` does maintain edge ordering. The solution based on adjacency matrices is much faster, but it does not maintain edge ordering.

Finally, the performance of these solutions depends on the kind of graph we use. Here's a better benchmark:

```
g1 = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "CondensedMatterCollaborations"}];
g2 = RandomGraph[{VertexCount[g1], EdgeCount[g1]}, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[1, EdgeCount[g1]]];
```

Let us preserve all graph options except edge weights. Re-building the graph from vertices and edges is actually slightly faster than re-building it with `Nucleus` for `g1`:

```
wg = g1;

ug = Activate[Nucleus[wg] /. Rule[EdgeWeight, _] -> Sequence[]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.22, Null} *)

ug = Graph[VertexList[wg], EdgeList[wg], FilterRules[Options[wg], Except[EdgeWeight]]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.15, Null} *)
```

For `g2`, the timings are `0.011` and `0.056`, i.e. `Nucleus` is significantly faster than the straightforward re-building.

Thus overall `Nucleus` is still a significant win for performance. But I am still hoping for further improvement, or at least a solution which is never slower than the naïve rebuild.

I believe that the overhead of `Nucleus` comes from re-evaluating all the graph options (3rd `Graph` argument), and may be possible to eliminate with an appropriately placed `Unevaluated`.

The implementation I settled on for the moment is a variation of Carl's `Nucleus` idea:

```
$graphLink::usage = "$graphLink is a loopback link used to convert atomic graphs to a compound form.";
transformGraphOptions::usage = "transformGraphOptions[fun][graph] applies fun to the list of options stored in graph.";
transformGraphOptions[fun_][g_?GraphQ] :=
    (
      If[Not@MemberQ[Links[], $graphLink],
        $graphLink = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback];
      ];
      With[
        {
          expr = AbortProtect[
            LinkWrite[$graphLink, g];
            LinkRead[$graphLink, Hold]
          ]
        },
        Replace[expr, Hold@Graph[v_, e_, opt : _ : {}, rest___] :> Graph[v, e, fun[opt], rest]]
      ]
    )

IGUnweighted[g_?IGEdgeWeightedQ] := transformGraphOptions[ FilterRules[#, Except[EdgeWeight]]& ][g]
IGUnweighted[g_?GraphQ] := g
```

For `g1` above it runs in about 0.18-0.19 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> Automatic] or Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> 2 weights] doesn't work?

Comment: @halmir That is precisely the problem. If `g` is already edge-weighted, neither of those affects the existing edge weights.  [Screenshot.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hgita.png)

Comment: @halmir Carl's solution much faster than what I had before, but it has one shortcoming: it does not preserve the edge ordering. If you have any other ideas, I am still very much interested.

Comment: @halmir As of Mathematica 11.2, is it true that the compound form of a graph (not the atomic expression, but the thing you get when passing it through a WSTP link) will always match the pattern `Graph[v_, e_, opt : _List : {}]`?  In other words, it always has at least two arguments, and if the third argument exists, it is a list of options. I feel that I'm walking on thin ice here.

Comment: Probably "Simple" graphs can use the `AdjacencyMatrix` approach without affecting edge ordering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

Thinking about this some more, my answer had three components:

1. "Inactivate" the Graph
2. Process the inactivated Graph
3. Activate the graph

For your example, the inactivate part (using `Nucleus`) took about .2 ms, while the activation part took about .45 ms. However, if all we care about is creating a graph with the same vertices and no weights, we could skip step 1 and just construct the graph using step 3. So, a slightly faster way to regenerate a graph with the right edge weights is the following:

```
ng = Graph[
    VertexList[wg],
    {Null, AdjacencyMatrix[wg]}
]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00043, Null}

And a check that `ng` has the same `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` as the original:

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g] === WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[ng]
```

> True

**Old answer**

You could use my [`Nucleus`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198/45431) function (which is derived from one of your ideas) to convert the [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) object to an [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) expression, delete or modify the offending [`EdgeWeight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeWeight) option, and then [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate). Here I repeat the `Nucleus` definition:

```
Nucleus[input_, head_:Automatic] := With[
    {
    atoms = Replace[head,
        {
        Automatic :> If[AtomQ[input], {Head[input]}, Message[Nucleus::atom]; $Failed],
        h_Symbol :> {h},
        h:{__Symbol} :> h,
        _ :> (Message[Nucleus::syms,head,2];$Failed)
        }
    ]
    },
    (
    If[!MemberQ[Links[], $AtomLink] || LinkReadyQ[$AtomLink],
        Quiet @ LinkClose[$AtomLink];
        $AtomLink = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback]
    ];
    LinkWrite[$AtomLink, input];
    inactiveBlock[atoms, LinkRead[$AtomLink]]
    ) /; atoms =!= $Failed
]

SetAttributes[inactiveBlock, HoldAll]
inactiveBlock[h_List, body_] := Block @@ Join[
    Apply[Set, Hold @ Evaluate @ Thread[{h,Inactive/@h}], {2}],
    Hold[body]
]

Nucleus::syms = "Argument `1` at position `2` is expected to be a symbol or a list of symbols";
Nucleus::atom = "Unable to determine atomic symbol";
```

Then, use `Nucleus`:

```
ng = Activate[Nucleus[wg] /. Rule[EdgeWeight,_]->Sequence[]]; //RepeatedTiming

WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[ng] === WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g]
```

> {0.00063, Null}
>
> True

A little over 4 times faster than rebuilding the Graph, but over 60 times slower than setting the initial weights, so I hope there's something better.

Comment: I wonder why `AdjacencyGraph[VertexList[wg], AdjacencyMatrix[wg]]` takes so much longer than your version.

Comment: Here's a more robust implementation of the idea under "Update": https://pastebin.com/7Tu2gQMX It will handle the special cases of empty, edgeless, directed, undirected and mixed graphs (I do not actually need mixed graphs, so I left the slow implementation for that one).

Comment: The `Nucleus` one might still be the better option because it preserves the edge ordering (and generally, the internal representation of the graph).